# Replace function that will replace specific Text to a class

Tags: jquery, html, replace

Hi I'm trying to write jQuery `replace` function that will replace specific text in the HTML to make a class.

I have find jQuery and Html. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/juTtG/20

It replaces a text character inside the brackets with `<b>hello world!</b>`

It's good, but I'm trying to replace more different text, like below:

I have Modified jQuery:

```
// this
var content = $("body").text().replace(/(\[this\])([\s\S]*)(\[\/this\])/gi,'<b>$2</b>');
console.log(content);
$("body").html(content);

// another
var content = $("body").text().replace(/(\[another\])([\s\S]*)(\[\/another\])/gi,'<b>$2</b>');
console.log(content);
$("body").html(content);

// more
var content = $("body").text().replace(/(\[more\])([\s\S]*)(\[\/more\])/gi,'<b>$2</b>');
console.log(content);
$("body").html(content);
```

Modified HTML:

```
[this]hello world 1![/this] [another]hello world 2![/another] [more]hello world more![/more]
```

See modified problem :http://jsfiddle.net/juTtG/384

The problem is it replaces replace one text character inside the `<b></b>`
I'm trying to replace more different text.
How to make this modified jQuery and HTML work.

*Another matter is, is it possible to replace by this:*

```
<div class="body"> Add a [newclass] </div>
```

To:

```
<div class="body">Add a <b class="newclass"></b> </div>
```

I'm hoping someone could give me a couple suggestions as what to try.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your "**Modified HTML**" problem, see [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juTtG/385/)

Here's the modified script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var content = $("body")
        .text()
        .replace(/(\[[\s\S]*?\])/gi, '<b>')
        .replace(/\[\/[\s\S]*?\]/gi, '</b>');
    $("body").html(content);
});
```

It turns this:

```
[this]hello world 1![/this] [another]hello world 2![/another] [more]hello world more![/more]
```

into this:

```
  <b>hello world 1!<b> <b>hello world 2!<b> <b>hello world more!<b>
```

---

**For this:**

```
<div class="body"> Add a [newclass] </div>
```

see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gw7kg4kt/)

Using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var content = $("body")
        .text()
        .replace(/\[([\s\S]*?)\]/ig, '<b class="$1"></b>');
    $("body").html(content);
});
```

Makes it this:

```
<div class="body">Add a <b class="newclass"></b> </div>
```

HTH,

-Ted

Comment: Woo nice. But how <div class="body"> Add a [newclass] </div> To:

<div class="body">Add a <b class="newclass"></b> </div>

Comment: Added that to the answer :)